# Access the second element of a tuple?

Tags: python, django

Here is what I have when I print `Meta.REQUEST_DOCUMENT_TYPE_CHOICES`

```
((u'void_cheque', <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ at 0x7fbc6951a4d0>),
 (u'pay_stub', <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ at 0x7fbc6951a510>),
 (u'bank_statement', <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ at 0x7fbc6951a550>),
 (u'bank_statement_60', <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ at 0x7fbc6951a5d0>),
 (u'csst_statement', <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ at 0x7fbc6951a650>),
 (u'saaq_statement', <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ at 0x7fbc6951a6d0>),
 (u'cara_statement', <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ at 0x7fbc6951a750>),
 (u'insurance_letter', <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ at 0x7fbc6951a7d0>),
 (u't4', <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ at 0x7fbc6951a850>),
 (u'welfare_chart', <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ at 0x7fbc6951a8d0>),
 (u'raqp_chart', <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ at 0x7fbc6951a950>),
 (u'customer_id', <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ at 0x7fbc6951a9d0>),
 (u'proof_of_residence',
  <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ at 0x7fbc6951aa50>),
 (u'bankruptcy_proof', <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ at 0x7fbc6951aad0>),
 (u'consumer_proposal', <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ at 0x7fbc6951ab50>),
 (u'signed_contract', <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ at 0x7fbc6951abd0>))
```

I have this kind of data structure, and I will like to access the second element `<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ at 0x7fbc6951a4d0>` in there using only `void_cheque`. How could I do such thing?

### Update

```
REQUEST_DOCUMENT_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('void_cheque',         _('Void Cheque')),
    ('pay_stub',            _('Pay Stub')),
    ('bank_statement',      _('Bank Statement (31 days)')),
    ('bank_statement_60',   _('Bank Statement (60 days)')),
    ('csst_statement',      _('CSST Statement')),
    ('saaq_statement',      _('SAAQ Statement')),
    ('cara_statement',      _('CARA Statement')),
    ('insurance_letter',    _('Insurance Letter')),
    ('t4',                  _('T4')),
    ('welfare_chart',       _('Welfare Chart')),
    ('raqp_chart',          _('RAQP Chart')),
    ('customer_id',         _('Customer ID')),
    ('proof_of_residence',  _('Proof Of Residence')),
    ('bankruptcy_proof',    _('Bankruptcy Proof')),
    ('consumer_proposal',   _('Consumer Proposal')),
    ('signed_contract',     _('Signed Contract')),
)
```

Comment: Add your code regarding this, may this is issue related to translations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to turn the list of tuples into a dictionary first, and then just use brackets to index it:

```
d = dict(...)
d['void_cheque']
```

Example:

```
>>> tuples = ((u'void_cheque', 42), (u'pay_stub', 1))
>>> d = dict(tuples)
>>> d
{'void_cheque': 42, 'pay_stub': 1}
>>> d['void_cheque']
42
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that all you need to do is simply:

```
Meta.REQUEST_DOCUMENT_TYPE_CHOICES[0][1]
```

And you'd get `Meta.REQUEST_DOCUMENT_TYPE_CHOICES` as a result.
We simply [accessed](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm) the first element of the tuple, and then accessed the 2nd element of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is related to django translation that send **proxy** type object of simple string.
You are using `from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _` in top of file 
So add new import in top of file like:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext
```

And update below tuple with ugettext, after that will return actual string from tuple

```
REQUEST_DOCUMENT_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('void_cheque',         ugettext('Void Cheque')),
    ('pay_stub',            ugettext('Pay Stub')),
    ('bank_statement',      ugettext('Bank Statement (31 days)')),
```